# Eclipse -- Progress windows don't show up any more

Tags: java, eclipse

I used to see both Building and Cleaning actions in their own separate windows, where I could wait for them to complete before continuing. Several weeks ago I must have clicked "Run in Background",  because now the progress only appears in a small, obscured Progress view.

[image: Not so nice.]

How do I set the progress of things like Java Build and Clean to appear in a popup dialog again?

[image: Nice.]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open the Eclipse Preferences, under `General` you will see `Always run in background`, uncheck it and you should be fine.

[image]