# How to go back to unchecked 'Always run in background' progress in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, progress

When installing or running something, there is a model dialog with a checkbox saying `Always run in background` as below snapshot.

My question is that after get it checked, how can I get it back to uncheck since the progress dialog will be minimized from then on.

[image]

Comment: not sure about this, but maybe under "general"->"always run in background"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse -- Progress windows don't show up any more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128723/eclipse-progress-windows-dont-show-up-any-more)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to restore them by unchecking the "Always run in background" box you find in the "General" page of the Eclipse Preferences.

[image]

[image]